# Creating model attributes at run time in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am creating an ember application where i want to implement a table built with ember. I am able to create a table using ember-models-table,and i am already able to render the table with column list and data. Now the problem is that the column list is coming from server and in ember-data i need to put all the columns as attributes in a model in order to show the data, so can someone help me in loading the column list in ember model at the run time.

my contoller is as follows

```
self.get("store").query("user",{page:1,pageSize:10}).then(function (data) 
            {
                self.set("data",data);
            });
```

my user model is as follws

```
/* With this it works */    
index: DS.attr("number"),
firstname: DS.attr("string"),
lastname: DS.attr("string"),
age: DS.attr("number"),
city: DS.attr("string")

/* but i want these attributes to be dynamic based on server response */
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data exists to specify the *data model*, i.e. the structure of the different kinds of data types you have. <sub>This structure, i.e. the `attrName: DS.attr('type')` specifications, is necessary for ember-data to track when a model instance should be considered "changed" (namely when one of named attributes changed; `user.set('foobar',42)` will work as expected but not count as change of the user object if `foobar` is not among the model attributes) and which attributes to send to the server on `.save()` (in this case, not `foobar`).</sub>

If you have an API endpoint that returns differently structured data depending on query parameters or anything, you arguably do not, in fact, have a data model, and might be better off not using ember-data.

If I recall ember-models-table correctly, it does not need an array of model instances as `data`, so you might as well make Ajax calls directly instead of via the `store`, wrap the objects of your flexible "server response" in `Ember.Object`s and pass an array of them to ember-models-table (or try passing the plain old json object array, i.e. the server response directly, which might work even although the documentation does not suggest it).

Comment: Thanks for your help , Anyway i am using an initializer now and hitting the server inside initializer and accordingly creating the model and registering it using Application.register, it seems to be working for me as of now.